# Torrent publishing message flow

Tags: protocols, bittorrent

I have been looking at the bittorrent protocol to understand how a torrent is initially created and shared. The only sources I've found are https://wiki.theory.org/BitTorrentSpecification#Tracker_HTTP.2FHTTPS_Protocol and http://www.kristenwidman.com/blog/how-to-write-a-bittorrent-client-part-1/.

However I still can't seem to figure out what how a new torrent created by a user is shared with the network (what messages are sent by the peer creating the torrent to the tracker etc.?). Any links / sources or help with this would be great.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Peers communicate with each other using TCP or Torrent Transport Protocol. Information about the file
to be downloaded (metainfo file) etc are communicated to peers using a peer protocol. As part of this
protocol, when peers communicate, they use a single byte of packet type to indicate their state.

For data transfer, the (sending) peer that has the file should move to unchoked state from the initial
choked state. On the other hand, the (receiving) peer should mtaintain an interested state during the
file transfer.

Here is the BitTorrent specification: http://www.bittorrent.org/beps/bep_0003.html

Comment: Hmmm... I'm not sure if I asked the question incorrectly but I would like to know how the first peer that creates a file communicates the creation to the tracker for the first time. (I did go through the official spec but that seems quite unhelpful to me at least).

Comment: Finding the .torrent metafile is an offline process. One can either download it directly or search for it on Google or BitTorrent  search engines (e.g. here: http://torrentz.eu/). The metafile contains the info about the tracker along with the file info. So, the peers that get the metafile, in fact, use it to find the trackers.

Comment: I think you're still not getting what I meant. My questions are all related to the torrent creation process not getting an existing torrent but rather the creation of one.

Comment: Your comment said "how the first peer that creates a file communicates the creation to the tracker for the first time." and I (accurately) replied to that :-) As far as creation of torrent file is concerned, there are several editors for that. In fact, most of the BitTorrent (software) clients should be able to create the torrent file for you. Hope that helps!

Comment: @ManojPandey: He's asking how those trackers become aware of the torrent's existence.